# UDP Throughput Calculation in NS3

Tags: udp, throughput, ns-3

I have a client/server topology in NS3 and I want to calculate the throughput of UDP traffic on the server.
This line of code `sink = StaticCast<PacketSink> (tcpServerApp.Get (0));` does not work because it can only be used in calculating the throughput of TCP packets. How can I calculate throughput for the received UDP traffic on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the throughput of UDP packets using the following code. You should use this code after `Simulation::Run();`

```
      uint64_t rxBytes = 0;

      rxBytes = payloadSize * DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get (0))->GetReceived ();
      double throughput = (rxBytes * 8) / (simulationTime * 1000000.0); //Mbit/s
      std::cout << "throughput = " << throughput << " Mbit/s" << std::endl;
```

Comment: I implemented this code but I got the SIGSEGV Error. What can be the problem?

Comment: First of all, this code should work. You need to change the variables accordingly. Without seeing your full error message, I can’t help you.

Comment: Thanks a million for your time. This is the code I used:  Simulator::Run ();
 uint64_t rxBytes = 0;    rxBytes = 1400 * DynamicCast<UdpServer> (ServerApp.Get (0))->GetReceived ();
      double throughput = (rxBytes * 8) / (10 * 1000000.0); //Mbit/s
      std::cout << "throughput = " << throughput << " Mbit/s" << std::endl;    and this is the error:   Command ['/home/reza/ns-3/ns-allinone-3.30/ns-3.30/build/scratch/my-complete-topology-quic-tcp'] terminated with signal SIGSEGV. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --command-template="gdb --args %s <args>").

Comment: Run it under gdb and you will explore more details about the error.