# how to calculate throughput of MANET routing protocols using NS3

Tags: routes, throughput, ns-3, overhead

I'm doing research on MANET routing protocols comparison.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the source code and how to calculate throughput and overhead throughput using NS3.

Comment: start with this https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/manet-routing-compare_8cc_source.html

Comment: i already tried this , but i don't know how to calculate through ,

Comment: see my answer for throughput here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076500/udp-throughput-calculation-in-ns3/61092575#61092575